# How to fill the select box in jsp page with values in database as well as showing its values as selected if data sent back by servlet to calling jsp?

Tags: jsp, servlets, javabeans

I am a beginner in the field of JSP, Servlets, and Java beans. I am working on a JSP file which contains an HTML form which creates the groups of users. I am trying to develop this form using MVC.

This form contains 2 textboxes and 2 select boxes. Out of these select boxes you can select multiple values one select box which contains users. Whenever first call given to the JSP page this user select box will get filled with usernames, which are fetched from database.

Whenever the form is submitted, it calls the servlet mentioned in the action method of the form. This servlet checks whether the user already exists in the database or not.

- If the group name does not exist in the database, then the group name and other form data will get saved and a reply attribute is sent back to the JSP page with the value "Success".
- If the group name already exists then a reply attribute is sent back to the JSP page with value "duplicate" and the rest of the form data is also sent back to JSP page so that this form data will get filled back in on the form.

Here is my JSP page's code:

```
<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
<jsp:useBean id="objbean" class="com.techspeed.user.CreateUserBean" />
<jsp:useBean id="objdao" class="com.techspeed.user.CreateUserDAO" />
<head>
   <title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
   <%
      if (null != request) {
         if (request.getAttribute("reply") != null) {
            if (request.getAttribute("reply").toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Duplicate")) {
               out.println("The entered Username is already exists!");
            } else if (request.getAttribute("reply").toString().equalsIgnoreCase("failed")) {
               out.println("User creation process terminated due to technical fault. Please try again later!");
            } else {
               out.println("The User created successfully!");
            }
            //out.println(request.getAttribute("reply"));
         }
      }
   %>
   <form name="creategroupform" method="post" action="Creategroup">
      <table width="422" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
         <tr>
            <th width="128" nowrap scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
            <th width="280" scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <th nowrap scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
            <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <th nowrap scope="col">
         <div align="left" class="grayBodyText style14">
            Group Name : 
         </div>
         </th>
         <th scope="col"><div align="left">
            <input type="text" name="username" value="">
         </div></th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Description<span class="style14">: </span></td>
            <!--I used JSTL to fill the value sent by servlet  -->
            <td><input type="text" name="lname" value=${lname}></td> 
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td><span class="style14">Group Type :</span></td>
            <td>
               <select name="role">
                  <!-- 
                  Here the JSTL is used to show a value as selected in 
                  select box which was selected by the user when form is submitted.
                  -->
                  <option value="Beginner" ${role == Beginner ? 'selected' : ''}>
                     Beginner
                  </option> 
                  <option value="Moderate" ${role == Moderate ? 'selected' : ''}>
                     Moderate
                  </option>
                  <option value="Expert" ${role == Expert ? 'selected' : ''}>
                     Expert
                  </option>
               </select>                          </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td><span class="style14">List Of Users: </span></td>

            <!-- Major problem starts here below -->
            <td><select name="groups" size="5" multiple>
                  <%
                     //objbean=objdao.createHtmlOptionList(objbean);
                     //out.println(objbean.getHtmGroupOptionList());
                     System.out.println("REached here!");

                     // This calls to getGroupList of method of DAO class which 
                     // retrives username and there unique userids from 
                     // database and stores in MAP collection of bean class.
                     if (request.getAttribute("reply") == null
                             || request.getAttribute("reply").toString().equalsIgnoreCase("success")) {
                        objdao.getUserList(objbean);
                        System.out.println("REached inside if!");
                  %>
                  <jsp:getProperty name="objbean" property="htmUseroptionList" />
                  <!-- 
                  In this JSTL the htmGroupOptionList property is a string 
                  variable name in bean class   which contains the 
                  preconstructed html code of <Options> haveing 
                  userid as value and username as name in Map collection Which 
                  gets constructed in above call to function getGroupList of 
                  DAO class getGroup. As per my thought this if block is gets 
                  executed whenever there is a fresh call given to this jsp 
                  page and when the reply attribute of the 
                  servlet contains value as "success" 
                  -->
                  <%
                     } else {
                        /* As per my thought this else block is get invoked 
                         whenever the reply attribute send by the servlet 
                         contains value as "Duplicate" of "Failed"  As per my 
                         thought this if block is gets executed whenever there 
                         is a fresh call given to this jsp page and when the 
                         reply attribute of the servlet contains value as "success" */
                        if (!(request.getAttribute("reply").toString().equalsIgnoreCase("success"))) {
                           objdao.getUserList(objbean);
                           // This Map have the list of userid as key and 
                           // username as value. This map is get filled from Database.
                           Map<Integer, String> userMap
                                   = (Map<Integer, String>) objbean.getUserList();
                           // This list contains the list of selected username 
                           // by the user before submitting the form.
                           ArrayList<String> lstSelUser
                                   = (ArrayList<String>) request.getAttribute("selUser");
                           String strSel = "";
                           for (Integer key : UserMap.keySet()) {

                              for (int i = 0; i < lstSelUser.size(); i++) {
                                 if (key.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(lstSelUser.get(i))) {
                                    strSel = "selected=\"selected\"";
                                    break;
                                 } else {
                                    System.out.println("not selected");
                                    strSel = "";
                                 }
                              }
                              out.println("<option value=" + key.toString() + " "
                                      + strSel + ">" + userMap.get(key) + "</option>");
                           }
                        }
                     }
                  %>                             
               </select></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
         </tr>              <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
               <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset">
               <!--<input type="reset" name="" value="Cancel"> -->
            </td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Here are my specific questions:

1. I have written some code to fill the user select box when the JSP page is called for the first time and when the control is sent back to the JSP page from the servlet. This code contains Java code. I think this solution to fill the user select box is not appropriate coding per the MVC pattern, i.e it's not a proper code design. I have read that it's not a good practice to write Java code in JSP. How do I fix this issue avoid Java code in my JSP so I abide by MVC pattern rules?
2. Regarding the userbean tag of the JSP page (lines 2 and 3), the object created using this tag is only used to fill the userlist box. I think this is also not optimal coding. How do I make this coding short and optimum?
3. When if the entered group name already exists in database then the servlet sets all data as attribute to request object and using request dispatcher forwards it to JSP page but here when the JSP page is displayed browser with prefilled form if you check the URL in address bar its not showing the JSP page name in the URL. It shows the servlet name. So how to get the JSPname back in address bar?
4. Is there any link on Internet which gives information regarding code design information with real word problems and examples like above for beginners?

Answer (score 0):

1. You could use MVC framework as Struts and bind all your properties with a model. Then when you display your combobox the value will be set from your model automatically.
2. As above.
3. You can use redirection instead of forwarding but it depends on the requirements.
4. Search Struts or Spring MVC.